# Problems using RabbitMQ

Tags: javascript, ubuntu, rabbitmq

I am new in using RabbitMQ. I have 2 problems.

1st: How do I delete all tasks from the respective queues in RabbitMQ which I have inserted previously? I have 5 different queues that are used to insert tasks using Ubuntu.

2nd: How do I grab the data from the RabbitmQ and display using a javascript at the frontend so I can monitor what are the current task(s) processing?

Please guide me along. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To delete all tasks you should call for each queue [queue.purge](http://www.rabbitmq.com/amqp-0-9-1-reference.html#queue.purge) method implemented in client library you are using.
To asynchronously get messages from queue you should use [basic.consume](http://www.rabbitmq.com/amqp-0-9-1-reference.html#basic.consume) method.